# My order action is not working `const { data } = await axios.post('/api/v1/order/new', order, config)` returns error code 500 internal server error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, e-commerce, mern

This is the orderActions.js

```js
console.log('test1');

export const createOrder = (order) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
console.log('test2');
        dispatch({ type: CREATE_ORDER_REQUEST })
        console.log('test3');
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }
        console.log('test4');
        const { data } = await axios.post('/api/v1/order/new', order, config)

        dispatch({
            type: CREATE_ORDER_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
        })
        console.log('test5');
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: CREATE_ORDER_FAIL,
            payload: error.response.data.message
        })
        console.log('test55', error);
    }
}

console.log('test6', createOrder);
```

My console.log shows

test1

test6 `order => async (dispatch, getState) => {.....}`

test2

test3

test4

but test5 doesnt show and i cant create a new order for my products

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to `await` createOrder in log6.
And you need to call createOrder as a function and pass in the order.

```
console.log('test6', await createOrder(anOrder))
```

Except, you say you get a 500 internal server error? Not sure how that's happening...

And shouldn't the method signature be like this?

```
export const createOrder = async (order, dispatch, getState) => {
```

Maybe I'm skimming the code too quickly...

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work

Comment: If you can update your question that might help. Show your actual code and output. As is, createOrder is a function that returns a function, so your console log should be createOrder(order)(dispatch, getState) or you shouldn't be seeing any of the logs inside createOrder. If you are actually hitting the server, 5xx errors mean the server had a problem. In this case, I'd suspect something in your request is making the server throw an error/crash - so look at the contents of 'order' or details in the server's log. Not seeing test5 or test55 is also a client-side issue though